# UTF 8 Regex for password

Tags: javascript, regex, utf-8

I am using the following regex to validate a password field in my JS code

```
^(?=.*[\p{Ll}])(?=.*[\p{Lu} ])(?=.*\d)[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\d]{8,}$
```

This essentially looks out for atleast 1 uppercase and one lowercase letter .

This fails to match text like Näppäimistö from the finnish dialect.

What should I do to get this working correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression; it works for my password field.

```
  (/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/)
```

Comment: OP says: *This essentially looks out for atleast 1 uppercase and one lowercase letter.* Does your pattern support that?

Comment: yes my friend, but it also for minimum 8 characters, 1 numbers etc. actually i forgot what's requirement it fulfills, but i never need to change this regex for my codes.

Comment: thanks @Jose castro.